# using the equals keyword in linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, equals-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lambda Expression: == vs. .Equals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273600/lambda-expression-vs-equals)

Hi,

I use a lot the keyword Equals to compare variables and other stuff.

but

```
wines = wines.Where(d => d.Region.Equals(paramRegion)).ToList();
```

return an error at runtime when in the data Region is NULL

I had to use the code

```
wines = wines.Where(d => d.Region == paramRegion).ToList();
```

to get rid of the error.

Any ideas why this raises an error?

Thanks.

Comment: `Equals` in this context isn't a keyword - it is just a method. There **is** a LINQ contextual `equals` keyword, but only when doing a `join`.

Comment: This question has been answered before:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273600/lambda-expression-vs-equals

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot call instance methods with null object reference. You should check that the Region is not null before calling its instance methods.

```
wines = wines.Where(d => d.Region != null && d.Region.Equals(paramRegion)).ToList();
```

The `d.Region == paramRegion` is (most likely) expanded to `object.Equals(d.Region, paramRegion)` and that static method does check whether the parameters are null or not before calling the Equals() method.

You can also write the condition in different order if you know that the `paramRegion` cannot be null.

```
Debug.Assert(paramRegion != null);
wines = wines.Where(d => paramRegion.Equals(d.Region)).ToList();
```

Comment: wines = wines.Where(d => object.Equals(d.Region, paramRegion)).ToList();

Answer (score 3):

Basically if

```
d.Region == null
```

then any method call, here it's *Equals(...)* on that will raise an exception since it's not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use:

```
paramRegion.Equals(d.Region)
```